# How to fetch metadata of mongodb database using springboot application

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'm a beginner in mongodb and springboot. I want to fetch all metadata of my database ; like I want all collections in a database, all fields of the database and all fields of a particular collection and their data types.

Is there any method I can fire queries like how we do for SQL database using spring boot jdbc .

Please help me out in this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

```java
ObjectId id =ru.findById(email).get().getFile_id();

GridFSFile gridFsFile = template.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(id)));

System.out.println("Print meta data" + gridFsFile.toString());
```

Here email is a unique key to find columns in particular row